# Negative integer Regex doesn't match

Tags: regex

I have Googled it, and found the following results:

- http://icfun.blogspot.com/2008/03/regular-expression-to-handle-negative.html
- http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3

With some (very basic) Regex knowledge, I figured this would work:

`r\.(^-?\d+)\.(^-?\d+)\.mcr`

For parsing such strings:

- r.0.0.mcr
- r.-1.5.mcr
- r.20.-1.mcr
- r.-1.-1.mcr

But I don't get a match on these.
Since I'm learning (or trying to learn) Regex, could you please explain why my pattern doesn't match (instead of just writing a new working one for me)? From what I understood, it goes like so:

- Match r
- Match a period
- Match a prefix negative sign or not, and store the group
- Match a period
- Match a prefix negative sign or not, and store the group
- Match a preiod
- Match mcr

But I'm wrong, apparently :).

Comment: +1 for the "Could you please explain why my pattern doesn't match (instead of just writing a new working one for me)?" attitude. :-)

Comment: Learning regex is most certainly a worthwhile endeavor! If you are serious, I would _highly_ recommend picking up a copy of Jeffrey Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Best book on Regex - ever!"). The time spent learning how to truly _craft_ a regex, will pay for itself in no time. When it comes to regex, there are two types of people in the world, those who have read this book and those who haven't. (You can easily spot the ones who haven't by all the `.*` expressions in their regexes!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. `^` matches the start of a string, so it should only be located at the start of a pattern (if you want to use it at all - that depends on whether you will also accept e.g. `abcr.0.0.mcr` or not). Similarly, one can use `$` (but only at the end of the pattern) to indicate that you will only accept strings that do not contain anything after what the pattern matches (so that e.g. `r.0.0.mcrabc` won't be accepted). Otherwise, I think it looks good.

Comment: @Lazlo: Good; that's what I had in mind. Just be aware that, as mentioned, without `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, this will also match e.g. `abcr.0.0.mcrabc` - but that is perhaps exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I'll add that in. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `^` characters are telling it to match only at the beginning of a line; since it's obviously not at the beginning of a line in either case, it fails to match.  In this case, you just need to remove both `^`s.  (I think what you're trying to say is "don't let anything else be in between these", but that's the default except at the start of the regex; you would need something like `.*` to make it allow additional characters between them.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `^` is not at the start of the expression, its meaning is 'not'. So in this case it means that there should not be a dash there.

Comment: `^` means "not" only inside of character classes; outside, it means "start of string".

Comment: Hmm, if that's true then the `^` might not work as there's also a `r\.` in front of it, making it impossible to be the start of the string.

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what the problem was. :-)